# How can I stop updating the RecyclerView in the fragment?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am currently creating an app in Android Studio via Kotlin, where **several fragments** (BottomNavigationBar) are bound in the MainActivity. In **one of the fragments is a RecyclerView**, which **gets the ArrayList from Firebase Realtime Database**.

The problem: Every time I go to the fragment with the RecyclerView, **it reloads the complete content (list from RecyclerView)**, because it may be that changing the fragments, it is destroyed and has to be reloaded every time?

And if it has to reload from the Firebase database all the time when changing the fragments, then **this is a considerable data consumption at Firebase**, which does not have to be!

How can this be done so that the data from the Firebase Realtime Database does not have to be downloaded again every time the database is reloaded?

I had looked to see if it was possible to **save the Custom ArrayList with OnSaveInstanceState, but unfortunately this is not possible** from my point of view because it is not possible to save a Custom ArrayList.

Here is an excerpt in the fragment with the RecyclerView:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sichtung, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        sichtungRecyclerview = view.findViewById(R.id.sichtung_listview)
        sichtungRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        sichtungRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
        adapter = sichtungAdapter()
        sichtungRecyclerview.adapter = adapter

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(sichtungViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.allSichtung.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.updateList(it)
        })
    }
```

-> sightingAdapter and sichtungViewModel is a separate Kotlin Class

Area for the fragments in MainActivity.kt:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView : BottomNavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Custom ViewModel:

```
class sichtungViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val repository : sichtungRepository
    private val _allSichtung = MutableLiveData<List<sichtungData>>()
    val allSichtung : LiveData<List<sichtungData>> = _allSichtung

    init {
        repository = sichtungRepository().getInstance()
        repository.loadSichtung(_allSichtung)
    }
}
```

Custom Repository:

```
class sichtungRepository {
    private val databaseReference : DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("sichtung")
    @Volatile private var INSTANCE : sichtungRepository ?= null

    fun getInstance(): sichtungRepository {
        return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this){
            val instance = sichtungRepository()
            INSTANCE = instance
            instance
        }
    }

    fun loadSichtung(sichtungList : MutableLiveData<List<sichtungData>>){
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    val _sichtungList : List<sichtungData> = snapshot.children.map { dataSnapshot ->
                        dataSnapshot.getValue(sichtungData::class.java)!!
                    }
                    sichtungList.postValue(_sichtungList)
                } catch (_: Exception){

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        })
    }
}
```

Update: I suspect that only the image from Firebase Storage is being loaded instead of the entire list. But if this is the reason, it is still difficult to save each item.

```
val storageRef = firebaseStorage.reference.child("nutzer/${currentitem.userid}.jpg")
        val localfile = File.createTempFile("tempProfile","jpg")
        storageRef.getFile(localfile).addOnSuccessListener {
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localfile.absolutePath)
            holder.image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
```

Comment: I strongly suggest showing the code you have now that doesn't work the way you want.  It's going to be easier to read that code instead of figure out what it might be doing based on your description.

Comment: Nothing you've shown is requerying the database every time your fragment is created (that's precisely why you do the query in your ViewModel, which will exist the entire time, even if the fragment itself is not currently present). What makes you think your ViewModel is manually reloading everything when the fragment comes back on screen? Please include your `sichtungViewModel` class as well.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information they asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @ianhanniballake edit with ViewModel

Comment: @AlexMamo Edit.

Comment: Please also show us the code in the repository class.

Comment: @AlexMamo Has been edited again.